# Is it possible to deserialize dictionary with dynamic values?

Tags: c#, json.net

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
}
```

I'm doing `DataContainer dataContainer=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataContainer>(text);`, but error says `RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'Krosenut.Tanks.DataContainer'`

Example of json:

```
{"_dictionary":{"Data 1":{"_dictionary":{"Integrity":200}},"Scene":"Mission 1 - encounter"}}
```

Comment: You didn't explicitly ask for Newtonsoft, so I've added a link to a `System.Text.Json` answer too. Answers show a) how to use dynamic and b) the recommended approach.